# Console output does not show number of elements of array. Array Elements not accessible in code

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise, axios

I have wasted hours on this but, was not able to find the answer to this problem.

Here is the code:

```
export const fetchZoneSlots = (name, startDate) => async dispatch => {

  var zoneSchedule=[], promises=[], temp=[],i,j;
  try {

    for(i=0;i<7;i++){

      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3090/zoneslots',
        {name, date: startDate}
      );

      promises.push(response);

      startDate= moment(startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD').add(1,'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }

    axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
      results.forEach(function(response) {
          temp.push(response.data);
      });
    });
    console.log(temp);

    dispatch({ type: ZONE_CHANGE, payload: temp });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: ZONE_ERROR, payload: 'Zone information cannot be fetch' });
  }
};
```

In the code above I fetched the data in form of array of objects and push this array into `temp` variable to create a matrix (2D-Array). Now I want to transpose this matrix. However, there is no output of `temp[i]` or `temp[i][j]` on console.

In other words, I cannot access the individual elements of the array. However, there is an output of `temp` which I have `console.log` in code which is shown in below image. 
[image]

As you can see in the image that the number of elements is not displayed on console it only shows `Array []` instead of `Array(7) [..]`.

However, if you notice that I have passed same var i.e. `temp` as value to my `payload` in `dispatch()`. Now, when I console log my component props then it properly shows `Array(7) [ (14)[..], ... ]` as value to `zoneSchedule` property.

So, I want to know why I am unable to access/iterate the array in my given code or why the number of elements is not shown in the console even though it contains the elements and length property is set. Why the same passed array is appearing property on other object property but the same thing does not work when I assign the `temp` to any other variable in my `action creator` code.

I want to transpose the temp before passing.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: you do console output outside of "then". data is not there yet. By the time you expand the array in console log, however, the data arrives. When you output a pointer to an object, its content may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `await` before `axios.all(...).then(...)` to wait for all the promises before doing the dispatch:

```
await axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  results.forEach(function(response) {
      temp.push(response.data);
  });
  return;
});
```